# What is causing this IndexOutOfBoudeException?

Tags: objective-c

I keep getting this indexOutOfBoundsException.  I can't figure out exactly what's causing it..

I've tried various array types, I've also defined a capacity of the array, but i keep hitting the error..

I've set an exception breakpoint which shows this line to be causing the issue.

Problem Line?

```
NSDictionary *subObject = [timprofiles objectAtIndex:i];
```

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < timprofiles.count; i++){

    NSString *tziid = @"";
    NSString *serial = @"";
    NSString *to_time = @"";
    NSString *from_time = @"";
    NSString *monday = @"";
    NSString *tueday = @"";
    NSString *wednesday = @"";
    NSString *thursday = @"";
    NSString *friday = @"";
    NSString *saturday = @"";
    NSString *sunday = @"";
    NSString *holiday = @"";
    NSString *special_day_one = @"";
    NSString *special_day_two = @"";

    NSDictionary *subObject = [timprofiles objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *tzid =  [subObject objectForKey:@"TZID"];
    NSString *tzitemid =  [subObject objectForKey:@"TZITEMID"];


     NSArray *timeprofiledegments = [subObject objectForKey:@"TIMEPROFILESUBSEGS"];

 //   NSLog(@"time profile segments %@", timeprofiledegments);

    for(int x = 0; x < timeprofiledegments.count; x++){


        NSDictionary *arryObjects = [timeprofiledegments objectAtIndex:i];

        tziid = [arryObjects objectForKey:@"TZIID"];
        serial = [arryObjects objectForKey:@"SERIAL"];


        NSString *timeSegList = [arryObjects objectForKey:@"TIMESLICE"];
        NSArray *splitarray = [timeSegList componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];


        for (int j = 0; j < splitarray.count; j++) {
            switch (j) {
                case 0:
                    from_time = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    to_time = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    monday = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tueday = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    wednesday = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    thursday = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 6:
                    friday = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 7:
                    saturday = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 8:
                    sunday = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 9:
                    holiday = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 10:
                    special_day_one = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 11:
                    special_day_two = [splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

             [timeProfilesList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tziid]];
             [timeProfilesList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tzid]];
             [timeProfilesList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",serial]];
             [timeProfilesList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",from_time]];
             [timeProfilesList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",to_time]];
             [timeProfilesList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",monday]];
             [timeProfilesList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tueday]];
             [timeProfilesList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",wednesday]];
             [timeProfilesList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",thursday]];
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the error cannot happen on the line you are mentioning but it should happen on line:

```
NSDictionary *arryObjects = [timeprofiledegments objectAtIndex:i];
```

Because you are using `i` as iterator and you should be using `x`.

The whole thing can be avoided using a for-each iterator:

```
for (NSDictionary *subObject in timprofiles) {
   ...
   for (NSDictionary *arryObjects in timeprofiledegments) {
```

Also note that your

`[timeProfilesList addObject:...]`

should be outside the inner-most `for` and there is no need to call `stringWithFormat` since your variables are already `NSString`.

Comment: That makes more sense! Yes, iterating 'i' was the cause...  Thanks for the tip, I'll improve my code.